# ReactJS + NodeJS: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" when user session expires

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I have implemented a simple authentication layer for my app and every time when the user session expires, I get this error message instead of being redirected on the homepage.
[image]

**redux/actions/authentication.js**:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER } from './types'; // we list here the actions we'll use
import setAuthToken from '../../setAuthToken';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const registerUser = (user, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/register', user)
            .then(res => history.push('/login'))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                });
            });
}

export const loginUser = (user) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/login', user)
        .then(res => {
            //console.log(res.data);
            const { token } = res.data;
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            setAuthToken(token);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            });
        });
}

export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: decoded
    }
}

export const logoutUser = (history) => dispatch => {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
    history.push('/login');
}
```

**src/App.js** (relevant part):

```
if(localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if(decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = '/login'
  }
}
```

The `/login` page exists. When this error appears - I can just refresh the page and the app will redirect me on `/`. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you add the complete App.js complete please ?

Comment: when you call logoutUser(), you're not passing anything in. So inside the function, history will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass your history object when you register logoutUser in your store.

```
if(decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser(history));
    window.location.href = '/login'
}
```

Otherwise it will be undefined

Comment: more like `logoutUser(history)(dispatch)`

Comment: I am trying both approaches outlined here, but it's failing due to `Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals`. Do I need to load the `history` to here somehow?

Comment: Testing it with `store.dispatch(this.props.history);`.

Comment: Is the history on the state object? If so then you shouldn't need to pass it in to the actions and you can just use getState() function

Comment: Using `store.dispatch(logoutUser(this.props.history));` returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`. @ageoff - can you give me, please, an example of that? Thank you

Comment: Show us how you dispatch the function `registerUser`. It will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

If the history is in your state then you can pull it back with getState(). If it is not in getState then as mentioned you would have to pass that value into your logoutUser call.

```js
if(localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if(decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = '/login'
  }
}

export const logoutUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
    getState().user.history.push('/login'); //replace user with wherever your history is within your state
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ageoff, thank you for your answer. I tested it and when I try to logout, I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`. I also tried to add `history` as a parameter to `logooutUser`, but it didn't help either.